# Leaving Singapore the day after visa period ends

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, singapore, overstaying

I am an Indian citizen travelling for a holiday to Singapore Malaysia and Thailand.

I will be arriving in Singapore on May 16th. Now the problem I am facing is that my Singapore visa (tourist visa) is valid for May 16th and 17th. I will be departing for Malaysia on 18th at around 10am. Will this pose a problem for me?

If yes, is it possible to extend the visa by a day so that I am not considered as staying illegally for the few hours I will be in Singapore on 18th?

Comment: I will be travelling to Malaysia via land...

Answer (score 5):

If your visa expires on May 17, and if you leave the country by May 18, it's still a one day overstay. 
There will be a fine to pay, but the worst thing is you will be registered as you overstayed. And trust me you don't want to do that.

Going to Malaysia from Singapore is one of the easiest overland border crossings.

You can easily take a bus from Singapore to Kuala Lampur.

If I were you, I would go to the woodlands by May 17, get my passport sealed, and go to Kuala Lampur by train. Woodlands is the Singapore side of the border, and Johor is the Malaysia side of the border. You can easily take a train to go to Kuala Lampur (takes about 5-7 hours).

You can also try to extend your visa. Since you have two weeks to do that, do it from the the Singapore embassy in India (Delhi one is quite friendly I heard).

Comment: About extending the Visa from the Singapore embassy... can it be done online?? or do i have to send my passport again?? because i need the passport atleast by 14th...

Comment: and another question... what is the latest time at which i could get a train from woodlands to malaysia??

Comment: If you are aiming to leave Singapore at the latest time possible on May 17, you can take public buses; they run at intervals of 15 minutes or less, and the last bus is close to (or after) midnight. These public buses will terminate in Johor Bahru (JB), the southern-most city of Malaysia; you can stay in a hotel overnight in JB and continue your journey the next day. (You will need a valid Malaysian visa, of course.)

Comment: Yes i already got my malaysian visa....
Ohh alright i'll probably take a bus..
Thanks for your help Ayesh... I really appreciate it...

Answer (score 3):

You have the following options:

1. Contact the Singaporean visa office and ask for an extension. Make sure you include copies of your flight tickets. This will help to get the extension.
2. Go back to the airport on the 17th late night (23:00), check in and go through immigration immediately. Stay in there until your flight leaves the next morning. The question will be if they let you check in that early. You will have to find out by calling the airline. Otherwise you are stuck in the entrance check-in hall of the airport and still have the same issue.
3. Overstay your visa. (Not recommended)

Comment: Do *not* overstay a Singaporean visa.  You will be fined (S$100/day, last I heard) and will experience considerable trouble getting new visas.

Comment: yes i am not favour of overstaying... i don't want to go through any trouble with the law over there...actually i will be travelling by bus to malaysia...